# Run and Debugging Application using hardware device but its showing usb device not recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, usb-drive, android-debug

I am trying to run and debug android project using hardware device. I have Huawei P8 Lite and whenever i enable developer mode and usb debugging from my phone, it shows the message that usb device not recognized. It happens just when i enable usb mood on developer options, otherwise its working fine if i want to transfer files between computer and phone.
I followed all these articles
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html
and also tried to update the driver software but computer shows that driver is updated.
IN device manager, under options universal serial bus controller, the usb port have yellow notification mark on it with the label that unknown device.

Please help. Emulator is killing me. Its very slow even after installing HAXM.

Answer (score 2):

Hi those instructions are for the google usb driver. To install the huawei adb driver and lte software, on your device (settings):

Enable Developer Mode.

Enable USB Debugging.

Connect your device via a usb cable.

You have to go to Computer -> double click on HiSuite

[image: CD Drive (G:) HiSuite]

Accept terms and click install. This should take about 30 seconds, after which you click start.

[image: After Installation]

Automatically, all drivers are installed as below.

[image]

The instructions are available on http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/faqs/detail/index.htm?id=6630

My breakdown according to my device (and country) and the link above are slightly different but the logic is the same. All the best!